# SDL Console output works when debuging, but not when run with the exe

Tags: c++, console, sdl, codeblocks, freopen

I am writing an experimental networking program, basically a test program for learning networking. I am using SDL and SDL_net in Code::Blocks with mingw, so the console output was being directed to stdout.txt. I searched around and found that you can fix this by including after SDL_Init():

```
freopen("CON", "w", stdout); //stops redirect of output
freopen("CON", "w", stderr); //and errors...
```

This worked perfectly, but only when building and running the program in the IDE: when run outside of the IDE ( e.g. double clicking on the program) the program runs properly, with the exception of the console output, which is still blank. As the program is supposed to be a console program this is a severe problem... I don't want to have to always run the program in the IDE to use it.

Any solution is apreciated but I would prefer that it was an alteration to the code, although in a pinch a batch file will do (I've read a couple of posts where this is the only thing that works, but they didn't go into much detail, so I can't replicate it). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you take a look at the [SDL Console FAQ](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/FAQ_Console)?

They provide many suggestions, including:

First try

```
freopen( "CON", "w", stdout );
freopen( "CON", "w", stderr );
```

If it doesn't work (like in your case), try

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
....
ofstream ctt("CON");
freopen( "CON", "w", stdout );
freopen( "CON", "w", stderr );
...
ctt.close();
```

OR

```
FILE * ctt = fopen("CON", "w" );
freopen( "CON", "w", stdout );
freopen( "CON", "w", stderr );
...
ctt.close();
```

Another option is to recompile the `SDLmain` library or add the `SDLmain` code to your project and stop linking against the library.

Comment: (Couldn't edit comment) Thanks for your response, that article is actually where I got my code, but I should have tried the other two methods first. Thanks again!

Comment: Are the other methods working for you? Rebuilding SDLmain would probably be a pain but hopefully the other solution works! - never mind, just saw your other post, did you try rebuilding SDLMain?

Comment: No, I haven't... For one I don't have enough experience to do it, for another the batch file works fine for now, but I might look into it at some point. Do you just compile it like normal code (into a .o file that is?)

Comment: Yes, if im not mistaken you should be able to get the project to build it on their Mercurial repository

Comment: It Worked! I looked back at the FAQ and saw it gave a tutorial for recompiling the library. Went through the tutorial (which was relatively short) and the new .a file works, without the .bat file. Thanks for all your help, Emartel.

Comment: The code above (as per the suggestions from the SDL FAQ) simply creates a file where the output is dumped. It shows nada in the console during the part of the code where SDL runs.

Answer (score 2):

## For (MinGW) SDL 2.0 users

SDL 2.0 disables the console by default, or rather, it does not enable it.
Since compiling with `-mwindows` disables the console, stdout does not point to anything. SDL_Log is a little fancier and can find the console using the windows API, but it can't capture stdin, because `cmd.exe` stole it :(.

SDL does not claim the console for various reasons, most likely because the program was compiled with `-mwindows`. Specifying `WinMain` as the entry point might also make `cmd.exe` reclaim the console. From what I've read `SDL_main` might redirect stdout and stderr.

You could probably get away with `#undef`'ing main, and/or

- call `AllocConsole();` after `SDL_init(...);`
- use `freopen("CON", stdout)`
- compile without `-mwindows` (`#undef`'ing `main` doesn't seem to have any effect)

but you should really just redirect stdout to e.g. cat, with `main | cat` (Always follow the rule "Don't `#undef` main unless you have to").

## TL; DR

To capture `stdout` for MinGW, simply redirect your program to `cat`: `main | cat`. This is a hack which simply makes sure stdout and stderr don't point to nothing.
To capture both `stdin` and `stdout`, compile without -mwindows to create a Windows console application. This will open a new window if necessary.

Note: It is especially important to flush output when using one of the above methods. Relying on line buffering is bad practice anyway.

Answer (score 1):

(I couldn't post this yesterday because I didn't have enough reputation)

Ok, did a little experimenting on the lines of the batch file. My resulting and (almost) working batch file:

```
program.exe
```

Didn't realise it would be this simple, but still can't understand why double clicking on the program doesn't work. I said almost working because after the client connects to the server the console blanks out, so there is still an issue. So, I still would really apreciate any help with this problem.

(End of yesterday's prospective post)

(Begining of today's answer)

I tried Emartel's suggestions but it still didn't work. Did some testing and discovered that an infinite loop of printing a empty string was causing the issue of the blank screen after connecting the client. Fixed the loop and now it works properly, although I still have to use the batch script.

Would apreciate knowing if someone ever figures out why double-clicking doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons:

- With SDL the console is disabled. SDL uses windows, not consoles.
- SDL redirects the standard output (both cout and printf()) to a file named stdout.txt in the same folder where the *.exe is located directory.

You can use:

```
std::cout << "Hello World";
```

And the message will be stored in the file stdout.txt.

Comment: Frankly this seems not to apply to the version in the Debian repos. I get no such file and `std::cout` works just fine. `printf` is the one causing problems. So it's better to say that it depends on the shipped version.